# Google Apps Script API Request with GraphQL parse error

Tags: json, google-apps-script, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to make API request with using Apps Script. API is GraphQL based.
I'm using JSON.stringify function. But API returns an error.

Request:

```
payload={"query":"{mutation {change_column_value (board_id: 177955, item_id: 287466289, column_id:\"phone\", value: \"{phone : 15065332974, countryShortName: \"US\" }\") {name column_values{ id value}}}"}}
```

I'm getting error;

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on \" }\" (STRING) at [1, 148]","locations":[{"line":1,"column":148}]}]}
```

Apps Script Code:

```
   var us = "US"
   var column_values = '{ \
     mutation {change_column_value (board_id: 177955, item_id: '+ 287466289  +', column_id:"phone", value: "{phone : 15065332974, countryShortName: \"' + us  +'\" }") {name column_values{ id value}} \
   }';    

    settings = {
      "method": "POST",    
      "headers": {"Content-Type" : "application/json","Authorization" : "eyJhbGciOiJIXXXXXXXXXX"},  
      "payload" : JSON.stringify({query:column_values})
    }

    response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, settings);
```

Comment: Just clarifying, is the `value` argument *supposed* to be a String with some JSON value inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets in a GraphQL operation indicate a *selection set* -- one or more fields that are being requested. The operation itself (whether a `query` or a `mutation`) is not a field, so you don't wrap the whole operation in brackets.

Correct:

```
mutation {
  doSomething
}
```

Incorrect:

```
{
  mutation {
    doSomething
  }
}
```

The *only* time you will see brackets that look like they are on the "outside" is when using [query shorthand](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations).

Provided that `value` is a String, then your use of backslashes to escape the double quotes *inside* that string should be fine.

You might also consider using [variables](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Variables), which would clean up your code considerably and make it less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

### You do not need to escape special characters inside a JSON request.

The [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) implies using key-value pairs assigned to each other with a colon, whereby strings are located inside quotes (not escaped with a backslash!), while numbers and variable names are not.

The brackets should be used in function of your desired API request as [documented](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations).